# Convert Nested dictionary to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like below

```
sample_dict = {
    0: {
        'Name': {'First': 'Jack', 'Last': 'Daniels'},
        'Age': 22,
        'University': 'BHU',
    },
    1: {
        'Name': {'First': 'Mark', 'Last': 'Zuckerberg'},
        'Age': 21,
        'University': 'JNU',
    },
    2: {
        'Name': {'First': 'Tim', 'Last': 'Cook'},
        'Age': 23,
        'University': 'DU',
    }
}
```

I would like to convert this dictionary into Dataframe

**Expected Output:**

```
        Name             Age       University
  First      Last  
  Jack       Daniels       22       BHU
  Mark       Zuckerberg    21       JNU
  Tim        Cook          23       DU
```

while performing the below code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(details).T
```

I'm getting the resultant output as:

```
                                      Name Age University
0     {'First': 'Jack', 'Last': 'Daniels'}  22        BHU
1  {'First': 'Mark', 'Last': 'Zuckerberg'}  21        JNU
2         {'First': 'Tim', 'Last': 'Cook'}  23         DU
```

Ideas are welcome!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(sample_dict).T
#Then:
df=pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Name').to_list()).add_prefix('Name.').join(df.add_prefix('.'))
#Finally:
df=df.sort_index(axis=1)
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('.',expand=True)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output

Comment: I dont want to pop name. Name has to be with Age and university in first row, and First and Last is below the name on second row

Comment: @kamaleshwaran Updated answer....Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Sorry...Still haven't achieved my expected output. Thanks

Comment: @kamaleshwaran got you....updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: ...Can I get age and university on first row rather than on second row?

Comment: @kamaleshwaran sure...updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 0):

[`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) is pretty powerful.  You could call that on the dict values.

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dict = {
    0: {
        'Name': {'First': 'Jack', 'Last': 'Daniels'},
        'Age': 22,
        'University': 'BHU',
    },
    1: {
        'Name': {'First': 'Mark', 'Last': 'Zuckerberg'},
        'Age': 21,
        'University': 'JNU',
    },
    2: {
        'Name': {'First': 'Tim', 'Last': 'Cook'},
        'Age': 23,
        'University': 'DU',
    }
} 


pd.json_normalize(sample_dict.values())
```

Output

```
   Age University Name.First   Name.Last
0   22        BHU       Jack     Daniels
1   21        JNU       Mark  Zuckerberg
2   23         DU        Tim        Cook
```

Comment: I kinda looking for name, age, university in first row, and First and Last in second row.Thanks